# Verb tense after "(non) appena"

Tags: conjunctions

Can I use the present and future tense after the conjunction "(non) appena" ? Is the same valid for the verb in the main clause? Does the meaning change between sentences in the two tenses? Example:

- (Non) Appena arriva mio  padre, mangiamo.
- (Non) Appena arriverà mio padre, mangeremo.

Answer (score 2):

According to the following interesting article from the [Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/rispondiamo-non-appena-possiamo/910) the usage of the expression “non appena”  for real events generally requires the same tense (present, future or past) for both  the main  and the secondary sentence.

> ***(Non) appena***  ha essenzialmente valore temporale, un valore che serve a sottolineare il succedersi ravvicinato di due azioni (quella della frase temporale e quella della reggente) e che può essere esclusivo e corrispondere quindi a ‘subito dopo che’, ‘quasi nello stesso momento in cui’, ma che può anche essere impiegato per esprimere un’eventualità, un’ipotesi con significato analogo a ‘quando’, ‘tutte le volte che’, ‘se’. Nel primo caso, quindi in frasi temporali che esprimono azioni ed eventi reali e non eventuali,
>
> (non) appena prevede il verbo all’indicativo: "non appena arrivi, chiama", "appena potrò, verrò a trovarti",

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not explain if there is there any difference between using the future or the present in this context.